# Android : how to detect already connected usb device?

Tags: android, usb

I'm trying to detect usb devices which are already connected to android.
I understand there are actions to detect when USB is either attached or detached. 
But I don't really get how to check devices after connecting usb device to android.
Also, I've found that each USB device has it's device class code, but how do I figure out what kind of device is connected? For instance, I need to detect both usb mouse and keyboard; how do I differentiate them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

1. First register Broadcast for USB connection.
   manifest permission:

:

```
<intent-filter> <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" /> </intent-filter>
```

2. Get the List of USB Device with details by using this

   ```
   public void getDetail() {
   UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

   HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
   Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
   while (deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
       UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();

       manager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
       String Model = device.getDeviceName();

       int DeviceID = device.getDeviceId();
       int Vendor = device.getVendorId();
       int Product = device.getProductId();
       int Class = device.getDeviceClass();
       int Subclass = device.getDeviceSubclass();

   }}
   ```

Comment: The device class and subclass should tell you information about the device, unless it is vendor specific - in which case you should be able to look at the VID/PID - but you'd have to know what vendor specific device you're looking for.

Comment: What is the `mPermissionIntent` ?? how can i create this ?

Answer (score 7):

Just to answer Benny's question here is what the mPermissionIntent could look like:

```
string actionString = context.PackageName + ".action.USB_PERMISSION";

PendingIntent mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, new 
Intent(actionString), 0);
mUsbManager.RequestPermission(device, permissionIntent);
```

Comment: `string actionString = context.PackageName + ".action.USB_PERMISSION";` is wrong. It should be `string actionString = context.PackageName + ".USB_PERMISSION";`