# Smartphone App that detects USB connection with PC. Reat Native

Tags: android, windows, react-native, usb

Is there a way to my App (React Native) detect that the device is connected with the PC?

I have this application that needs to detect if the device (Android) is connected with the PC (Windows) via USB, and then make some procedures. A simple return with `true||false` would be enough. Something like calling the function:

```
isConnectedViaUSB() // returns true or false.
```

Comment: i think you'd better write your own native modules, these link could be useful: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30182172/android-how-to-detect-already-connected-usb-device
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600896/android-detecting-usb

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to find a shortcut for that because there are so many other things to do and I need so little of this function. But thank you for the links, they're very useful!